# Is there a way to convert JSON Data to avro schema in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net, avro

I'm trying to convert the input json data to avro schema.
Converting a Json schema to Avro schema is possible with confluents avro serialization.
But what about JSON data to Avro Schema?

Input

```
{
   "name": "first Name",
   "age": "25",
}
```

The expected output would be an Avro schema.

Comment: I think you're asking for an Avro **record**, not a schema. Also, Confluent tools cannot do what you are saying, AFAIK

Comment: There are some Java libraries that can convert back and forth between the two schema formats, so it's certainly possible. Maybe they use a dynamic object as an intermediate before extracting the schema and serializing to avro.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro.AvroSerializer`. This code copied from here can help:

https://www.csharpcodi.com/csharp-examples/Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro.AvroSerializer.Create(Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro.AvroSerializerSettings)/

```
    public Task<byte[]> Serialize<TData>(TData data)
        where TData : class
    {
        using (var buffer = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Serialize the data.
            var avroSerializer = Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro.AvroSerializer.Create<TData>(_settings);

            avroSerializer.Serialize(buffer, data);

            // Return the contents of the buffer.
            buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return Task.FromResult(buffer.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Here TData is a model which can be serialised to Json.

Comment: I want to convert JSON Data to Avro schema.

Comment: @me_ Write a model class, deserialize the JSON to it, then pass it to this shown function. There is no direct translation