# How JSON data can be converted to Avro schema in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I don't want to use Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro.
Is there any way to convert JSON data directly to Avro schema in C# and asp.net core API.

Example: Json Data:
`{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}`

Avro Schema:

````
  "name": "MyClass",
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "com.acme.avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "age",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "car",
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    }
  ]
}```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to convert JSON Data to avro schema in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59464635/is-there-a-way-to-convert-json-data-to-avro-schema-in-c)

Comment: That answer is using deprecated library and I already mentioned that I don't want to use Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro.  @PeterBons

Comment: Ok, how about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45338832/can-a-c-sharp-model-be-serialized-as-an-avro-json-schema)

Comment: Most of the answers are using "Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro.AvroSerializer". It is a deprecated package. So I don't want to use it in my application and it is the reason that I am looking for an alternative. @PeterBons